# Any tools to keep database structure continuously synchronised in PHP / MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-schema

I have 3 development environments - dev, staging and production. (PHP/MYSQL)

I am looking for a tool to synchonise my database structure across each development 
environment.

I have a master_db_structure.sql file that contains the current database structure file.

So what I need to happen is:

IF

I add a new table or update a table structure in dev (and then export entire db structure to master_db_structure.sql)

THEN

Staging automatically applies a 'CREATE TABLE' or 'ALTER TABLE' because it looks at its current structure & compares it to the master_db_structure.sql file

---

In the past I've use mysqldiff tool to create a database 'patch' file but isnt there a better way to do this?

Hoping one of you boffins can help.

Comment: I also found a tool that PHPMYADMIN has - http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/FAQ_9.1
But I have been unable to configure a new connection to the remote server which is not much of a help.

Comment: Ok I managed to make a connection using PHPMYADMIN to my remote database - but then found that the synchronise function timed out. I investigated the documentation and found (http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/Documentation.html#faq9_1) that the SYNCHRONISE function is limited to 'small tables'.
Its a pity (I have 10 tables and one iwth 50,000+ records) as I think its configured by default to sync structure AND data (data being the beastly one) - otherwise this would have been a perfect one click solution....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a migrations tool, it seems. I use Doctrine's, but that's part of a larger library. [This](https://bitbucket.org/idler/mmp) looks like it could be what you want.

Comment: This was a simple lightweight tool that did more than I expected - I will be using this tool.

Comment: link is rotten now

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out this tool: [MySQL-PHP-AutoMigrations](https://github.com/Billiam/MySQL-PHP-AutoMigrations)

Comment: Looks great but a little heavyweight for me.

Answer (score 0):

I use MySQL work bench, it has a lot of useful tools, including a schema synchronizer.

http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

Comment: Not as far as i know, its more of you make the change in the work bench and then you synchronize the different schemas with it.

Comment: I had a problem with this - it seems to only be able to sync databases with the same name ie it cant sync 'db_1' with 'db_2' - they both have to be called 'db_1'

Answer (score 0):

You can always check [Redbean](http://redbeanphp.com) I used them in a project before and it was really nice to deal with

All you have is to write php code and it will modify you database!